# Install Error Pygame

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed. I installed pygame through `sudo apt-get python-pygame` and also from the source. When I tried `>>>import pygame` on Python I get this error:

`

```
>>> import pygame<br>
Jello, world!<br>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 255, in <module>
    try: import pygame.surfarray
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/surfarray.py", line 69, in <module>
    import pygame._numpysurfarray as numpysf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/_numpysurfarray.py", line 48, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    import polynomial
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from polynomial import Polynomial
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py", line 60, in <module>
    from polytemplate import polytemplate
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/polytemplate.py", line 20, in <module>
    polytemplate = string.Template('''
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Template'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/multipart.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 14, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/quoprimime.py", line 48, in <module>
    from string import hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name hexdigits

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 255, in <module>
    try: import pygame.surfarray
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/surfarray.py", line 69, in <module>
    import pygame._numpysurfarray as numpysf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/_numpysurfarray.py", line 48, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    import polynomial
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from polynomial import Polynomial
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py", line 60, in <module>
    from polytemplate import polytemplate
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/polytemplate.py", line 20, in <module>
    polytemplate = string.Template('''
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Template'
```

I saw the Jello World so I guess it is working a bit. I dont know what to do. I appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you don't have SDL installed on your box.

Remove your current pygame packages then dot he following:

**wget http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz**

**tar -xzvf SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz**

**cd SDL-1.2.14**

**./configure**

**make**

**make install**

Once this has completed reinstall pygame but try reinstalling via easy_install or pip:

**easy_install pygame**

or

**pip install pygame**

You should be good to go after that.